# Finding block list from allowed list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming

We will pass a policy list to the function. Policy list contains a list of entities.We need to return list of entities that cannot talk to each other.
Eg. policy1 = [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']] This policy1 means that B-C traffic allowed rest all is denied. We need to return list of entities that cannot talk to each other.
block_list = [('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'D')]

Similarly for policy2 = [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']] where B can communicate directly with A,C but A and C cannot communicate with each other and cannot communicate D. D cannot communicate with each other(A,B,C). block_list = [('A', 'C', 'D'),  ('B', 'D')]

Similarly for policy3 = [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E']];
A cannot communicate with any other entity. B and C can communicate with each other but not with others(A,D,E),
block_list = [('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'E')]

Similary for policy4 = [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F'], ['G']] ; block_list =[('A', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'G'), ('A', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G'), ('A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'G'), ('A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'G')]

I wrote code

```
from itertools import product

def generate_block_list(policy):
    block_set = set()

    # Generate block list for each entity in the policy
    for entity in policy:
        other_entities = [e for e in policy if e != entity]

        # Generate all possible combinations of the current entity with other entities
        combinations = list(product(entity, *other_entities))
        unique_combinations = [tuple(sorted(set(combination))) for combination in combinations]

        # Add combinations to the block list
        block_set.update(unique_combinations)

    block_list = list(block_set)
    return block_list

# Example usage:
policy1 = [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]
block_list1 = generate_block_list(policy1)
print("\nPolicy:", policy1)
print("Block List:", block_list1)

policy2 = [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]
block_list2 = generate_block_list(policy2)
print("\nPolicy:", policy2)
print("Block List:", block_list2)

policy3 = [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E']]
block_list3 = generate_block_list(policy3)
print("\nPolicy:", policy3)
print("Block List:", block_list3)

policy4 = [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F'], ['G']]
block_list4 = generate_block_list(policy4)
print("\nPolicy:", policy4)
print("Block List:", block_list4)
```

I got output :

Policy: [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]
Block List: [('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'D')]

Policy: [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]
Block List: [('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')]

Policy: [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E']]
Block List: [('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'E')]

Policy: [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F'], ['G']]
Block List: [('A', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'G'), ('A', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G'), ('A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'G'), ('A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'G')]

It is failing for policy2 where entities are common. Help me fix. Or suggest a better way to do. Block List: [('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')] is wrong it should be Block List: [('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'D')]

Comment: this becomes insanely inefficient to compute very quickly. If something isn't in the "allowed list" obviously it's going to be in the "block list". It's easy to define a function that tells you if something is allowed or not. Do you really need to compute the entire "block list"?

Comment: There is nothing such as allowed list, we need block list (who needs to be isolated from one another) for further computation. This is not some standalone function. It is small part of bigger code.

Comment: your "policy" IS the allowed list. Either way, you can specify one and calculate the inverse of it. why do you need BOTH the "policy" AND then"block list"?

Comment: We need "block list" as a part of backend . We take policy from UI and convert it to "block list" and pass via API. So yeah we need it.

Comment: @OM222O we shall focus on providing a solution or improving the existing code, rather than questioning the question.

Comment: @rockstar can you not redesign your system? imagine if you have 10 nodes (A to J) and only a few connections (lets say `[[A,B,C],[C,D],[D,E,F]]`) the blocklist for that combination is going to be massive. choose EITHER the policy OR the block list and calculate one from the other when you need

Comment: @AyushRaj if someone asks about writing bogo sort (yes, that is a real algorithm), I think we should at least tell them that there are better solutions.

Comment: @OM222O As I suggested this is a small part of a larger codebase, so not possible to refactor at this stage. Well as of now we will have a fixed limit on max node. So massive calculation or complexity doesn't matter. We just need a solution to it.

Comment: Can you suggest some code changes to improve . that shall be helpful.

Comment: You have chosen a really poor data structure to do this.  Even if it were to work as requested, you'd have to inspect each tuple in the list, parse it out, and check that a connection was valid.  You should be using a dictionary of allowed or disallowed connections or a set of allowed/disallowed connection tuples that would both provide constant-time access for checking

Comment: It's hard to guess how the logic generalizes. What should be the output for `[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['F', 'G']]`? Can you provide more complex examples?

Comment: Hey, @mozway how abt policy = [{'A', 'B'}, {'C', 'B'}, {'D'}, {'A', 'E'}, {'E', 'B'}, {'E', 'C'}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're not using the built-in combination method and only calculating certain combinations and not others, but something like this should work:

```
from itertools import combinations

def all_combinations(lst):
    for i in range(2,len(lst)+1):
        for combination in combinations(lst,i):
            yield set(combination)

def is_allowed(combination,allowed_connections):
    for connection in allowed_connections:
        if connection == combination:
            return True
    return False
            
policy = [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]
all_nodes = [item for group in policy for item in group]
allowed_connections = [set(group) for group in policy if len(group)>1]
block_list = [combination for combination in all_combinations(all_nodes) if not is_allowed(combination,allowed_connections)]
print(block_list)
```

this will block everything that is not explicitly allowed.

Comment: bcoz this sol of urs is highly inefficent , it returns this long list [{'B', 'A'}, {'A', 'C'}, {'A', 'D'}, {'B', 'D'}, {'C', 'D'}, {'B', 'A', 'C'}, {'B', 'A', 'D'}, {'A', 'C', 'D'}, {'B', 'C', 'D'}, {'B', 'A', 'C', 'D'}] when it can be done with [('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'D')].

Comment: I literally said this is an explosive solution and it can't scale at all. How is `[('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'D')]` enough when for example `[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C')]` is not allowed either? I can't see how A and B or A and C are allowed to communicate. Your original question REQUIRES a HIGHLY INEFFICIENT solution.

Comment: We require the smallest possible set of solution. When entire solution set can be represented with [('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'D')] why do I need to use more tuple?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
from itertools import combinations, product
from pprint import pprint

test_cases = [
    [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["D"]],
    [["A"], ["B", "C"], ["D"]],
    [["A"], ["B", "C"], ["D", "E"]],
    [["A"], ["B", "C"], ["D", "E"], ["F"], ["G"]],
]


def is_connected(c, possible):
    for v in c:
        if possible.get(v, set()).intersection(c):
            return True
    return False


for policy in test_cases:
    possible = {}
    for p in policy:
        for c1, c2 in combinations(p, 2):
            possible.setdefault(c1, set()).add(c2)
            possible.setdefault(c2, set()).add(c1)

    out = [c for c in map(set, product(*policy)) if not is_connected(c, possible)]
    print(f"{policy=}")
    pprint(out, width=30)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
policy=[['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]
[{'A', 'C', 'D'}, {'B', 'D'}]

policy=[['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]
[{'A', 'B', 'D'},
 {'A', 'C', 'D'}]

policy=[['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E']]
[{'A', 'B', 'D'},
 {'A', 'B', 'E'},
 {'A', 'C', 'D'},
 {'A', 'C', 'E'}]

policy=[['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F'], ['G']]
[{'A', 'B', 'G', 'F', 'D'},
 {'E', 'A', 'B', 'G', 'F'},
 {'C', 'A', 'G', 'F', 'D'},
 {'E', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'F'}]
```

---

EDIT: Version 2:

```py
from itertools import combinations, product
from pprint import pprint

test_cases = [
    [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["D"]],
    [["A"], ["B", "C"], ["D"]],
    [["A"], ["B", "C"], ["D", "E"]],
    [["A"], ["B", "C"], ["D", "E"], ["F"], ["G"]],
    [{"A", "B"}, {"C", "B"}, {"D"}, {"A", "E"}, {"E", "B"}, {"E", "C"}],
]


def is_connected(c, possible):
    for v in c:
        if possible.get(v, set()).intersection(c):
            return True
    return False


for policy in test_cases:
    possible = {}
    for p in policy:
        for c1, c2 in combinations(p, 2):
            possible.setdefault(c1, set()).add(c2)
            possible.setdefault(c2, set()).add(c1)

    tmp = set()
    for p in map(set, product(*policy)):
        for i in range(1, len(p) + 1):
            for c in combinations(p, i):
                if not is_connected(c, possible):
                    tmp.add(frozenset(c))
    tmp = sorted(tmp, key=len)

    out = []
    while tmp:
        s = tmp.pop()
        tmp = [i for i in tmp if not i.issubset(s)]
        out.append(set(s))

    print(f"{policy=}")
    pprint(out, width=30)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
policy=[['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]
[{'A', 'C', 'D'}, {'D', 'B'}]

policy=[['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]
[{'A', 'D', 'B'},
 {'A', 'C', 'D'}]

policy=[['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E']]
[{'A', 'E', 'B'},
 {'A', 'E', 'C'},
 {'A', 'D', 'B'},
 {'A', 'C', 'D'}]

policy=[['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F'], ['G']]
[{'F', 'G', 'B', 'A', 'D'},
 {'F', 'G', 'B', 'A', 'E'},
 {'C', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'E'},
 {'C', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'D'}]

policy=[{'A', 'B'}, {'C', 'B'}, {'D'}, {'A', 'E'}, {'E', 'B'}, {'C', 'E'}]
[{'A', 'C', 'D'},
 {'D', 'B'},
 {'E', 'D'}]
```

Comment: Thanks I shall run some more tests and if it passes will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Hey, this fails for policy = [{'A', 'B'}, {'C', 'B'}, {'D'}, {'A', 'E'}, {'E', 'B'}, {'E', 'C'}]
like D is blocked from all A is blocked from E

Comment: @rockstar And what should be the result in this case?

Comment: @rockstar I've added new version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no control of the data structure that you receive the "allowed" connections in, here is an example that generates a set of blocked connections rather efficiently.  Having the blocked (or allowed) connections in a more appropriate dataset allows for constant time checking of membership.

If you have many many nodes, you should probably switch over to a dictionary of allowed connections from each node, which would be better than enumerating them as this example does.

#### Code:

```
from itertools import combinations as c
from typing import Iterable

allowed =  [['A'], ['B', 'C', 'E'], ['D']]

def block_list(allowed) -> set:
    all_nodes = {t for tt in allowed for t in tt}
    allowed_connex = set()
    for t in allowed:
        if len(t) > 1:
            allowed_connex.update(c(sorted(t), 2))
    all_connex = set(c(sorted(all_nodes), 2))
    blocked_connex = all_connex - allowed_connex
    return blocked_connex

def is_blocked(connection, blocked_connex: Iterable) -> bool:
    return tuple(sorted(connection)) in blocked_connex

# example
allowed = [['A'], ['B', 'C', 'E'], ['D']]
blocked = block_list(allowed)
print(f"Connection B-A is blocked: {is_blocked(('B', 'A'), blocked)}")

# policy 2 example
allowed_2 = [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['D']]
blocked_2 = block_list(allowed_2)
print(blocked_2)
```

#### Output:

```
Connection B-A is blocked: True
{('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D')}
```

Comment: highly inefficent when ur solution returns {('B', 'D'), ('A', 'C'), ('D', 'E'), ('A', 'E'), ('A', 'D'), ('C', 'D'), ('A', 'B')} instead of [('A', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'D')] which is there in my original solution. I just wanted to deal with cases where entities are common and didn't wanna expand the list size.